# How to change the text of a TextBlock of an already loaded window using a button from another window in WPF C#?

Tags: c#, wpf

As the title describes, I need to change the text of a TextBlock of a window using a button from another window.

The structure of the app is as follows:

**SplashScreen->Show WindowA (Where TextBlock is located)->SplashScreen is Hidden->Show Login->Hide Login->Show Home (Home contains the button to hopefully change the text of TextBlock from WindowA).**

How do I do this? In WinForms, I can simply create an instance of the Form and set its Label text to a particular value.

I tried to use a getter setter on the Home window so that I can access the value on WindowA but it always seem to return null though it isn't on the Home window.

Any help would be appreciated. I'm currently lost on how to implement this since I'm still learning WPF.

Answer (score 1):

My preference is to use something like this

```
    public class Changeable<T> : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private T currentValue;
        public Changeable(T initialCurrentValue) => currentValue = initialCurrentValue;
        public T Value
        {
            get => currentValue;
            set
            {
                if (!EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(this.currentValue, value))
                {
                    this.currentValue = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged();
                }
            }
        }
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

// In your modelView, set this in the constructor to the shared object
public Changeable<string> MyText {get;}
// in your xaml
<TextBox Text={Binding MyText.Value} />
```

This allow you to create a single value that is shared between multiple windows, while ensuring that the UI is updated whenever the value is changed.

Comment: So I need to add the code for Changeable class to the window where the button is right? Then also add the Changeable<string> MyText on the constructor on where the Changeable class? Lastly, I'll then set a Binding property on the window where the textblock is located right?

Comment: @DennisManicaniJr. Not really? you put the class wherever you want. You put a property of that class in your viewModels, and initialize it such that both view models share the same object. This does presume you are using MVVM.

Comment: I can't seem to get the value from the other window. I can set and get the value from the window with the button, but I can't get it on the window where the TextBlock is located. Steps I made: Create a class with the code you provided above. Next, I instantiated it on Home window in where I set the value of Changeable to a certain string. I can get it again on the same window to show the value of Changeable. I then instantiated Changeable on WindowA, then set the value of Text property of TextBlock to {Binding header.Value} where header is the one I instantiated but it returns null.

Comment: @DennisManicaniJr. The whole point is to have a *single shared object*. So, when your home window creates windowA it should hand over a reference to the object. But you are talking about windows when you should be talking about viewModels, I would highly recommend reading about [MVVM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/maui/mvvm) if you are going to use WPF

Comment: Ah yes now I understand, since I'm using multiple views, I won't be able to utilize data binding. I've watched this very informative video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gOf2FZ6dkbU) about the INotifyPropertyChanged. It only uses only one view. Thanks for the answer though. I've finally understood about data binding.

Comment: @DennisManicaniJr. Data binding works just fine with multiple views, you just need to ensure that each view has its DataContext object set to the correct viewModel. Either by injecting it in the constructor for the view, or by binding the DataContext. By default the dataContext will be inherited from the parent-view, and that may also be fine.